# Get href value in PHP RegExp using specifice attribute

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to get those link value whose attribute is `data-gaevent="people"` 
In this case this is first link.

```
<a class="clickstream-link" data-clickstream-record-number="0" data-gaaction="people_serp_0" data-gaevent="people" data-galabel="click" href="/name/Raymundo-Mario-J/Santa-Ana-CA/c7z9sd9" itemprop="url" rel="nofollow">  


<a class="clickstream-link" data-clickstream-record-number="0" data-gaaction="people_serp_0" data-gaevent="anyother" data-galabel="click" href="/name/Raymundo-Mario-J/Santa-Ana-CA/c7z9sd9" itemprop="url" rel="nofollow">
```

Here is RegExp:

```
<a.*href="(.*)"
```

How can I set condition in RegEXP

Comment: Better use DOM than regex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Presuming data-gaevent is always before the href...

```
$url = '<a class="clickstream-link" data-clickstream-record-number="0" data-gaaction="people_serp_0" data-gaevent="people" data-galabel="click" href="/name/Raymundo-Mario-J/Santa-Ana-CA/c7z9sd9" itemprop="url" rel="nofollow">';
preg_match('~<a.*?data-gaevent="people".*?\s+href="(.*?)".*~', $url, $link);
echo $link[1];
```